# Using the getName Method

Tags: java

Include the following:

1. A method getFirstName that will return a Student object's first name
2. A method getLastName that will return a Student object's last name
3. A statement to print "The student's first name is " with your first name returned from the getFirstName method.
4. A statement to print "The student's last name is " with your last name returned from the getLastName method.

This is what I have so far:

```
public class Student
{
    //the student's full name
    String FirstName;
    String LastName;

    /**
    * Create a new student with a given name a
    */
    public Student(String name)
    {
        FirstName = name;
        LastName = name;
    }  

    /**
    * Return the first name of this student
    */
    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return FirstName;
    }

    /**
    * Return the last name of this student
    */
    public String getLastName()
    {
        return LastName;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //gives a name to the students
        Student FirstName = new Student("Samantha");
        Student LastName = new Student("Jones");

        //each object calls the getName method
        System.out.println("The students first name is: " +Student.getFirstName());
        System.out.println("The students last name is: " +Student.getLastName());
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to have a first name and a last name your constructor should take two string parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a new object but do not use it later.

You should add a second argument to the Student constructor for lastname:

```
public Student(String firstname, String lastname)
{
    FirstName = firstname;
    LastName = lastname;
}
```

And in main, use your student-objects after creation.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //gives a name to the students
    Student stud1 = new Student("Samantha", "Jones");
    Student stud2 = new Student("Timo", "Hantee");    

    //each object calls the getName method
    System.out.println("The students first name is: " + stud1.getFirstName());
    System.out.println("The students last name is: " + stud2.getLastName());    
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much I have been trying to figure this out for like an hour. It is working now :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace with that:

```
public Student(String _firstname, String _lastname)//constructor header
   {
      FirstName = _firstname;//description of constructors
      LastName = _lastname;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Student Class, the FirstName and LastName are two different variable, so you need to assign different values to it in your constructor. So rather creating constructor with one argument, create it with two arguments, one for firstName and other for lastName. Like below:

```
public Student(String firstName, String lastName)//constructor header
   {
      this.firstName = firstName;//description of constructors
      this.lastName = lastName;
 }

public static void main(String[] args)
{
  //gives a name to the students
  Student student= new Student("Samantha", "Jones");

  //each object calls the getName method
  System.out.println("The students first name is: " +student.getFirstName());
  System.out.println("The students last name is: " +student.getLastName());

  }
```

Here I would like to suggest you one more thing, that is very important for java programmers, follow Java Naming Conventions. The variable name should be start with small letter.